How to access a class of a sub-namespace form a class in the base namespace?
Example of what is giving me an error, I'm trying to get a class that is in a sub-namespace(if that is what you even call it):
namespace Namespace::Namespace2
{
    class A
    {
    public:
        void DoStuff();
    };

    class B : public A
    {
    public:
        void DoMoreStuff();
    };
}

namespace Namespace
{
    template <typename T>
    bool IsBaseOfA()
    {
        if (std::is_base_of<Namespace2::A, T>::value) // Gives me error because it cant find Namespace2::A
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

This code give me the error: 'Namespace2': is not a member of 'Namespace'

"Gives me error" -- which error? Errors must be posted verbatim and complete in code blocks so questions can be found by users that get similar issues.

You forgot to include <type_traits> and have a typo in `return true. With those fixed there is no problem : https://godbolt.org/z/n7hav9Wbn

I am having tho make a lot of guesses, and a couple corrections, in my attempt to duplicate your problem. It is very important that you provide a code example that reproduces the problem you are asking about. I also strongly recommend that you include the error message you are receiving.

Side note you can also use the shorter version for is_base_of<>::value, std::is_base_of_v<>

I went a little further than Pepjin did with my attempt in case the compiler totally ignored the template since it's never used. Same result though: No error. This means We've made a few assumptions that are different from yours. Unless we know your assumptions we can't answer this one with anything but a guess.

"sub-namespace(if that is what you even call it)" -- Try "nested namespace". (See #8 in Namespaces @ cppreference.com.)
